# Swift: Print Coordinates from Firebase: 0,1 - 2,3 instead of 0,1 - 1,2

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I am trying to print locations for each row in IndexPath.row because the IndexPath.row determine which specific content they want to receive in the TableView.

The NSDictionary from Firebase looks like: `x,y,x,y,x,y` and so on in coordinates.

0,1 = first coordinates
2,3 = second coordinates

```
Output: [55.617804300000003, 12.98939, 55.601572900000001, 12.979585399999999, 34.506667999999998, -81.948334000000003, -7.0909109999999993, 107.668887]
```

So first 0 and 1 is x, y for first coordinates with following:

```
print(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: openLocations[indexPath.row], longitude: openLocations[indexPath.row + 1]))
```

How our results is at the moment:

```
x= longitude, y = altitude

x, y
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
5, 6
```

How it should be:

```
x= longitude, y = altitude

x, y
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
6, 7
8, 9
```

NSDictonary looks like:

x,y,x,y,x,y ..

This should be an easy task but my mind at the moment is somewhere else, if any could help me straight this out, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance,

Sincerely yours,

Filip

Comment: Your dictionary does not look as a dictionary at all, more like an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take every second row:

```
latitude: openLocations[2 * indexPath.row], longitude: openLocations[2 * indexPath.row + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality what you have is an Array, you can loop throught then like (asumming that you receive the locations in pair):

```
var openLocations = [55.617804300000003, 12.98939, 55.601572900000001, 12.979585399999999, 34.506667999999998, -81.948334000000003, -7.0909109999999993, 107.668887]
for(var i = 0; i < openLocations.count; i += 2){
     let location = CLLocationCoordiante2D(latitude: openLocations[i], longitude: openLocations[i+1])
     print(location)
}
```

In the case to work with IndexPath and UITableView, first you have some options:

***Option 1:*** 
First map the data that you recieve from firebase to a datastructure that bind the locations. Ex. It can be an Array of CLLocationCoordinate2D or you're own structure that you want.

***Option 2:***
You need to do some modifications on the datasource method, suppose:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
     return openLocations.count / 2
 }
```